# Sql question marks in insert statement

Tags: sql, database, prepared-statement

This may seem a very rudimentary question but I am not clear about it. In my code I have a query

```
    "insert into CONTACTS (EMAIL, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, TELEPHONE) values (?, ?, ?, ?)"
```

What is the '?' in the values, is it to fetch the real time values?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using ?

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur most RDBMSes that support prepared statements use ? to denote the placeholders

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is coming from some [prepared statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).  Those question marks will be populated with values later on, before the query is executed.

Comment: It is worth noting that the reason they exist is mainly for security reasons. i.e. the SQL Injection problem.

Answer (score 3):

**In programming context where you need to insert multiple set of data into same table-**

If you need to insert multiple set of values into database table then there is no need to prepare statement every-time to insert the new value. You will just prepare the insert statement once and will use this prepared with different set of values.These '?' acts as placeholder for different set of values which will be populated later during the time of execution. It results better performance.

**It you are using this with database prompt** then it is basically used to let user give input at command prompt. It will give prompt to user to insert data.

Please go through " [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) " to know how we can avoid sql injunction by using '?'.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help, I appreciate it

Comment: check this out 
[Secure_Coding_SQL_Injection](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_SQL_Injection)